# There are 2 red, 3 pink, 4 orange, and 5 yellow jelly beans in the pocket. how many different ways can you choose at least one jelly bean?

Tags: probability, data-analysis

Thanks a lot!There are 2 red, 3 pink, 4 orange, and 5 yellow jelly beans in the pocket. how many different ways can you choose at least one jelly bean?

Comment: What do you know about the problem?  What have you done to try an solve it?

Comment: Forget about the "at least one" part for a while. Stop in front of the red jelly beans. We can choose $0$ or $1$ or $2$, so $3$ choices. Now stop in front of the pinks.

Comment: Is choosing a pink then a yellow different from choosing a yellow then a pink?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is asking...

Comment: the answer is (2+1)(3+1)(4+1)(5+1)-1=359

Comment: but I don't get that

Answer (score 0):

**Red**

There are two reds, we can either choose $0$, $1$ or $2$ reds.

**Pink**

There are three pinks, we can either choose $0$, $1$, $2$ or $3$ pinks.

**Orange**

There are four orange beans, we can choose $0$, $1$, $2$ , $3$ or $4$ of them.

**Yellow**

Five yellow, our choices are $0$, $1$, $2$ , $3$, $4$ or $5$

We have $3$ choices for red beans, $4$ choices for pink beans, $5$ choices for Orange beans and $6$ choices for yellow beans.

Overall, our choices are:

$(3)(4)(5)(6) = 360$

We must perform a final operation before we have our answer.